# Change BackGround Image of button for a few seconds only

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF app that uses Buttons (surprise)

I have styled it so that when the User clicks on the button the background image is changed to a red color.

What I want to happen is that after a few seconds the background reverts back to its original background.

I am not sure how to do this.

This is my code so far:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">                       
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource RedButtonBackGround}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="74"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="27"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource ButtonBackGround}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This would be pretty easy to do in C# code...
Does it need to be in XAML?

Comment: Hi, it does not need to be but I prefer to keep UI stuff in xaml you see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change color of button in wpf C# after click and after 2 minutes retain the original color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674662/change-color-of-button-in-wpf-c-sharp-after-click-and-after-2-minutes-retain-the)

Comment: @Tyress no it is not. I am using images. thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson my bad

Comment: @Tyress but appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution to how animate the background image based on DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames and opacity.

**Update - 2 Button style code (put to your resource section)**

```
        <ImageBrush x:Key="KoalaImageBrushKey" ImageSource="Images/Koala.jpg"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="RedButtonBackGround" ImageSource="Images/RedButtonBackGround.jpg"/>
    <Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="MyBorder" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource RedButtonBackGround}" BorderThickness="1">
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource KoalaImageBrushKey}"/>
    </Style>
```

1. First DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames section changes the RectangleVisibleOnCklick's opacity from 1 to 0. in 2 sec.
2. Second DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames section changes the MyBorder's opacity from 0 to 1. in 2 sec.
3. To make the animation to be faster change the KeyTime parameters of both DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames sections:

**Options**

```
                                       <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.75" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**or**

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**Elliptic button with a Elliptic content**

```
        <ImageBrush x:Key="KoalaImageBrushKey" ImageSource="Images/Koala.jpg"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="PinguinsImageBrushKey" ImageSource="Images/Penguins.jpg"/>
    <Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="MyBorder" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MyBorder}"></VisualBrush>
                            </ContentPresenter.OpacityMask>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" Fill="{StaticResource PinguinsImageBrushKey}" Opacity="0"></Ellipse>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource KoalaImageBrushKey}"/>
    </Style>
```

**Rectangle button with elliptic content (is elliptic when clicked due to KeyFrames animation using)**

```
        <ImageBrush x:Key="KoalaImageBrushKey" ImageSource="Images/Koala.jpg"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="PinguinsImageBrushKey" ImageSource="Images/Penguins.jpg"/>
    <Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="MyBorder" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <ContentPresenter.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MyBorder}"></VisualBrush>
                            </ContentPresenter.OpacityMask>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" Fill="{StaticResource PinguinsImageBrushKey}" Opacity="0"></Ellipse>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleVisibleOnCklick" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.25" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="0.5" />
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1.0" />
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource KoalaImageBrushKey}"/>
    </Style>
```

Regards.

Comment: @Andrew Simpson here is animation using ImageBrush.

Comment: Thanks I shall take a look when back home

Comment: @AndrewSimpson you can manage that, just remove a  EasingDoubleKeyFrame(s).

Comment: Hi, i think it is more a case of my lack of knowledge. CSS in web sites is definitely not my strong point and styling in wpf is similar to me.  The image I had was a blue rounded button and whilst the transparency affect works really well I get a flat (not rounded) red button.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson in case you want to get a rounded button, you should create a rounded button. the fact that the content of the button is rounded doesn't means that the button will be rounded as its content. do you need a rounded button?

Comment: <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>

Comment: is what I am currently using to get the desired affect I want and I want it to be replicated when the background is red too

Comment: @AndrewSimpson please update your question in a way we other people will be able to understand what about the article. please write what do you want will happened when you click the button.

Comment: hi, I have only just got back in. I will update and answer everyone who has been kind enough to reply. thanks

Comment: hi again, but very quickly I have added a comment indicating the desired look and feel of my button,  It is also in the original question?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Hi, please check the Updated Button style code section. There is an updated rounded rectangel with red background is visible when you click the button.

Comment: Hi, it is kind of you to keep trying to help me but my button uses 2 images:  ButtonBackGround and RedButtonBackGround.  All I want is this 2nd image displayed for a few seconds and then replaced with the original one after keypress. The button itself has a border style round it that makes it rounded,  I cannot see where you are using the 2nd image in your code example?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson please add the ImageBrush as a resource  pointing to your image(ImageSource), and set the background of your inner border (named RectangleVisibleOnCklick) to be relative to the added ImageBrush resource. please see the update-2 section.

Comment: hi, i put that in and the buttons do toggle between the 2 images - thanks - but the transition is a bit slow.  how do i quicken this up? I tried playing around with the key times but all i succeeded in doing was never showing the original image again?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                        <ColorAnimation To="Blue" Duration="0:0:4" />
                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" BeginTime="0:1:52" Duration="0:0:4" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674662/change-color-of-button-in-wpf-c-sharp-after-click-and-after-2-minutes-retain-the) (by sa_ddam213)

Comment: Sorry this does not work for changing the image back ground?

Comment: I think a combination out of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443854/xaml-storyboard-for-background-imagebrush) and the answer should be what you are looking for...